# php simplexml_load_file don't accept ascii codes

Tags: php

I am using simplexml_load_file to parse a xml file.
But I am getting Warning and the result is empty.

PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): /usr/www/go.actionads.ru/htdocs/data/downloads/feed_8.xml:8787: parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 1 in /user/htdocs/includes/YMLParser.class.php on line 178

It's because the xmlFile contains ascii codes such as ^A and ^M
and the simplexml_load_file don't interpret them.

How to solve this problem?

I have done replacement these characters by using str_replace. But this method is badly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the XML file contain those characters in the first place?

Comment: The XML file is generated not by me.  <br/> ^A is the ascii code exactly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start-of-Header#SOH